# C# open a webpage and see if it was closed

Tags: c#, process, tabs, browser-tab

I am trying to keep track of a webpage; whether it was closed, specifically. I use this code to open processes and keep track of close:

```
this.Process = new Process();
this.Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
this.Process.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);

this.Process.StartInfo.FileName = this.ProcessPath;
this.Process.StartInfo.Arguments = this.Arguments;
this.Process.Start();

private void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
}
```

This works fine for other types of processes, like batch files (it'll print "Exiting..." when I close them). However, if I use it to open a webpage and then close that webpage, it'll never print "Exiting". I assume this is because the browser can have multiple tabs and it's waiting for the whole browser to close. How can I keep track of the specific tab being exited?

Comment: I don't think you reliably can unless you restrict it to a specific browser. Depending on the browser the way it handles tabs is different, you would need to write code to check on all browsers and even then some of them might not support it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Maybe someone will know of a way. Thanks for letting me know. I'll try a different approach.

Comment: Generally, if you open a web page, the user expects to "own" that window from then on - e.g. they may decide to browse elsewhere, etc. They should be treated as "fire & forget" by your original process.

Comment: One option you may want to investigate is launch a window within your app that has a embedded web browser in it. See [here for WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here for WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx). Using that you can just listen to the window closed event from inside your program.

Comment: I think I'm going to go down the "fire & forget" route as it's a console application, so I wouldn't be able to embed a web browser. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: What does "closing a web page" even mean?  You can close the browser.  But, what if it has multiple tabs, is it closing one web page or many?  Also, a browser loads a page and displays it.  The "web page" isn't really "opened" after that.  Based on your code it looks like you want to see if the *browser* is closed.  Maybe if you detail more of what you're trying to accomplish instead of how you're trying to accomplish it, someone can offer some advice.